# Emacs IDO (Interactively Do Things) for vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugins

Is there a vim equivalent of Emacs' [ido mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) ([video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kvyvXl5gjI0))?

What I mean is that I want to type

```
:e a
```

and it should show me a shortened list of files starting with `'a'`. When I type `b`, it would automatically update this list to show only files starting with `'ab'`.

Vim's wildmenu does not cut it as it is **not** updated **interactively** as I type (as it is in Emacs). I have to constantly press `<TAB>` for it to update (after I type anything).

In other words I'm looking for something similar to CtrlP, but something that would integrate itself with vim's command line and would work for all cases whenever wildmenu could be/is used (not something invoked via a special shortcut).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like with emacs, fuzzy/as-you-type completion doesn't exist in vim so you need a script. Maybe vim.org has what you want?

SkyBison would be close to what you want: it is halfway between IDO and CtrlP.

https://github.com/paradigm/SkyBison

Comment: It's a far cry from Emacs' IDO. But for the lack of a better alternative, I'm going to accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into Vim that does what you want.  It is possible someone has attempted to write a Vim plugin that adds this behavior, but I did not spot anything with a quick Google search.

***Edit:*** There are some plugins for in-buffer, as-you-type auto completion, but I am not aware of any that work on the :-command line.

Answer (score 0):

I believe FuzzyFinder will do what you want:
https://bitbucket.org/ns9tks/vim-fuzzyfinder/

Comment: Not really. I've used it before. CtrlP is much better than that. Also, I want something to complete my command line commands (like :e) with filenames, not something separate like this plugin.